# Session ID containing username?

Tags: cookies, session-management

Is it safe to append the user's username to the session ID? The session ID is 32 bytes long generated using a secure PRNG. I encode it using base64 URL to save it in a HttpOnly cookie. The cookie value would be `base64URLEncode(rand32bytes.username)`.

Comment: When you say "I encode it using base64 URL...", can you clarify? Are you encoding this value in Base64 and then passing it to the user via URL? Or do you mean you are URL encoding AND Base64 encoding the session key?

Comment: I'm using base64 URL encoding so it's safe for urls

Comment: Okay, so then are you sending the session key in URLs at all? Are you using GET parameters to pass the session key around? AKA does the session key ever appear in URLs in your application?

Comment: No, it never appears in URLs. Its stored as a httponly cookie.

Comment: Okay, well in that case there really isn't any need to use base64url encoding as simply base64 would do the job, but I digress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is okay, but *only* because you are including a sufficiently long secure PRNG value. In fact, it should be pointed out that the username appended to the session ID actually adds absolutely **no** value, what-so-ever. It does not decrease the security of your created session key, but it also does not increase its security, either. This is because, if an attacker wanted to try and guess the session of another user, they would *only* need to guess the random value, as the username is known so they could simply append it.

I am assuming that you are appending the username to the session ID not to increase the entropy of the session keyspace (make it harder to guess), but so you can send the username along with the session key and use them both elsewhere. I would suggest that you don't do this for multiple reasons.

1. You could simply send both values in a JSON encoded string like `{'user':'civ15','sessionID':'123456'}`. Pulling these would be as simple as parsing the JSON object and then accessing `json['sessionID']` or `json['user']`. There are libraries that can do this for you, instead of you taking the time to create your own parsing implementation.
2. Aside from being easier though, it may be more secure, too. If you implement your own parsing function, you have to think about how it can be abused. What if a malicious actor sends you a bunch of junk data? Would it crash your program? Could they inject code and execute commands? It all depends on how you implement it of course, but by parsing yourself (without a library) you have to account for ALL of this.
3. Using standards like JSON is beneficial because it makes the code easier for others to understand. I'm not sure about the scale of this project, but if you're working with other people, having standards can avoid mistakes while keeping everyone on the same page. Or, maybe later down the road you have a new question for stack overflow about sessions. If you use your own implementation you will probably have to explain everything you have done in your own way as opposed to just dropping the term "JSON".

**EDIT:**
I've seen in your comments that you are looking for a way to have multiple sessions associated with one user, and you want to be able to invalidate them all at once. I am not super familiar with redis, however after a simple search I understand it as an in-memory database structure which stores data in key-value pairs. So, why can't you just create a list of relational values in the form `{'username': 'sessionID'}`? I assume, if this is a database like structure, that you can search the list on `username` or `sessionID`. By doing this, you could simply have multiple entries with the same `username`, and pull all entries which have the `username` you are looking for. You could also search this list on `sessionID` to validate users.

Answer (score 2):

It's not dangerous in and of itself, but I would still advice against it for two reasons:

- It serves no purpose. If you want to make the session ID harder to guess, just add more random data instead.
- It might be tempting to use the username from the session ID instead of fetching it from the server side session store or the database. This would be a security vulnerability, since users could impersonate each other just by changing a cookie.

Comment: I need a way to be able to identify all the user sessions (in redis) and invalidate or modify all of them if I want to, that's why I thought about this approach? You think it's bad?

Comment: @civ15 Without knowing the details of your setup, I can't say for sure. But there are pitfalls here. What you need to think about is this: What happends if a user changes her cookie to include the same random part, but a different username?

Comment: @civ15 Consider if there are any solutions where you store the username in redis, but don't include it in the session ID.

Comment: Nothing, because I filter by username, if that session is not associated to the initial username they can't fake it.

Comment: @civ15 Then I think you would be fine as long as any other part of your application doesn't rely on the username from the session ID. But I would still be careful with this setup. Since I am not that good with redis I can't suggest a good alternative, though.

Comment: @civ15, in 5 years, when you've won a lottery jackpot or gotten a better job, and your application is in the hands of a junior dev who is a few credits away from graduating college, is that junior dev going to be tempted to use the username as a shortcut when implementing a new feature, rather than strictly double-check the session ID storage every single time?

Comment: @civ15 you should add those implementation details into the question. As it stands, I do not see why this was the chosen solution for the problem.

Comment: That is, I mean username in the cookie, not this answer.

Comment: "I need a way to be able to identify all the user sessions (in redis) and invalidate or modify all of them if I want to, that's why I thought about this approach? You think it's bad?" - The way Microsoft Identity accomplishes this for authentication cookies is via a security stamp in the database. Cookies are tagged with the current security stamp.  Validating a session is done by comparing it to the security stamp.  Invalidating all sessions is done by modifying the security stamp in the database (causing any future validation checks to fail).

Comment: Equivalently, you could use a timestamp instead of a security stamp, with an invalidation being done by modifying the timestamp in the database so that it is newer than the timestamp in the sessions.  This can sometimes be more convenient (no need to look up the stamp when creating new sessions), but I generally don't recommend it.